# Youtube Data API-debugging authentication errors

Tags: youtube-api

Getting authentication errors when I try and obtain my upload authorization token
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_error_responses

Using a packet sniffer, my first error message is>

```
401 Token invalid - Invalid token: Cannot parse AuthSub token:
```

In addition to perhaps improperly formatted Auth key value, I'm wondering exactly what headers I should be including for my upload auth request.

I am using the following though think clientId has been deprecated

```
 "Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth=\"" + authToken + "\""
"X-GData-Client", clientId
"X-GData-Key", "key=" + devKey
```

---

After changing

```
"Authorization", "AuthSub token="+authToken
```

to

```
Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth="+authToken
```

in my request I no longer get 'Cannot parse AuthSub token' error message but

I still get

```
Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken

<errors>
<error>
    <domain>yt:authentication</domain>
    <code>Unknown</code>
</error>
</errors>
```

Stumped.  Would really appreciate any feedback as I'm not even certain now where my error(s) exist!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok working but not really sure how:)

Am using these 2 headers in my POST request to
     'http://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken'

```
"Authorization",  "GoogleLogin auth="+authToken
"X-GData-Key", "key=" + devKey
```

And also needed to associate my youtube user developer credentials with a channel

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/youtube-api-gdata/76x8vaADJWM/36O05FD7mC0J

A packet sniffer or at least adding support to read the XMl error responses is essential!

Answer (score -1):

I resolved this problem by providing the correct developer key